# Обновление блока вместе с  jQuery/JS

Tags: jquery, html, php, css, javascript

У меня есть выпадающий список

```
<select>
 <option>Привет</option>
 <option>Пока</option>
</select>
<div id="bla"></div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь выбирает "Привет" в блоке с id="bla" появлялась цифра 1, когда "Пока" - цифра 2. И все без перезагрузки страницы.

Нужно для вывода цены товара. Т.е. Привет, Пока - это товары, а цифры - цены. Все будет генериться через PHP, поэтому Надо все в HTML держать.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select>
    <option value="1">Привет</option>
    <option value="2">Пока</option>
  </select>
  <div id="bla"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("select").change(function() {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        str += $(this).val() + " ";
      });
      $("#bla").text(str);
    }).change();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

примерно так

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="chan(this)">
 <option>Привет</option>
 <option>Пока</option>
</select>
<div id="bla"></div>

<script>

function chan(elem){

    if(elem.selectedIndex==0){
        document.getElementById('bla').innerHTML=1
        }
        else{
                if(elem.selectedIndex==1){
        document.getElementById('bla').innerHTML=2
        }
            }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Не универсально. Данные в JS плохо. Надо бы в HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $('#order').bind('change',function(){
      $('#order_price').html($('#order option:selected').attr('title'));
   });
});
```

Вот нужное мне решение на jQuery. Цену берем из атрибута title и никаких громоздких (относительно) JS кодов

Comment: В следующий раз подробней обьясняйте, что значит "*данные не в js, а в html*".

И еще вмето `.bind('change',function(){...})`, советую написать `.change(fuction(){...})` — так еще компактнее.

Comment: для кастомных данных используйте атрибуты типа data-*, например `data-title`. Валидаторы просят использовать теги по назначению

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так

html

```
<form>
<select name="product" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
 <option value="1">Привет</option>
 <option value="2">Пока</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="bla"></div>
```

---

js

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("bla").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // Код для IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // Код для IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 2 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("bla").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","product.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

---

product.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Не удается подключиться: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Привет</th>
<th>Пока</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```